# R - How would I check to see if columns corresponding to a given group are all equal within a group?

Tags: r

Let's say I have data like this:

```
group value
1     0
1     0
1     0
2     1
2     0
3     1
3     0
4     1
4     1
```

How would I iterate through all values of "group" to see if the values corresponding with the group have all equal values. I want to have a dataset that includes ONLY groups where the values are not identical.  I'm not sure of an easy way to do this avoiding a for loop.

Comment: Does it need to be in base R, or are you open to packages?

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(length(unique(value)) > 1)` should do the trick.

Comment: can use `n_distinct(value)` instead of `length(unique(value))`

Comment: @DMC didn't know about that function. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
tapply(DF$value, DF$group, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1L

#     1     2     3     4 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

To subset the table, write the same with `ave`:

```
DF[ ave(DF$value, DF$group, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))  > 1L, ]

#   group value
# 4     2     1
# 5     2     0
# 6     3     1
# 7     3     0
```

With packages, the latter step looks like...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, if (uniqueN(value) > 1L) .SD, by=group]

# or
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(n_distinct(value) > 1L)
```

Comment: You're some kind of wizard.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `table`

```
tbl <- rowSums(table(df1)>0)>1
subset(df1, group %in% names(tbl)[tbl])
#  group value
#4     2     1
#5     2     0
#6     3     1
#7     3     0
```